# Uniqueness of Galois descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, galois-descent, frobenius-map

Let $Y,Z$ be $\mathbb{F}_p$-schemes, they are both models of scheme $X$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ . Let $F$ be the absolute Frobenius of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, If $1_Y\times F$ and $1_Z\times F$, two endomorphisms of X are equal, can we deduce that $Y\cong Z$?

Comment: Yes, that is part of descent for coherent sheaves: consider the pushforward of the structure sheaf of the graph of an isomorphism in $(Y\times_{\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{F}_p} Z)\times_{\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{F}_p} \text{Spec}\ \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.